# ASP more quotes in function inside a tag element

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to make *alert* with value from *DataBinder* inside a tag element. I try many variations with quotes, but still no success.

My code

```
OnClientClick='alert(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "path", "{0}")%>);'
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: i posted answer try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function Check(a) {
                alert(a);
            }

        </script>
```

Code Behind:

```
 OnClientClick=<%# "Check('" + Eval("path") +"')"%> runat="server" />
```

Or simply

```
  OnClientClick=<%# "alert('" + Eval("Id") +"')"%> runat="server" />
```